# AngularJS dynamic scope variable not accepting white spaces

Tags: angularjs, variables, dynamic, angularjs-scope

I have to create dynamic scope variables and AngularJS.
when I tried the following code it works.

```
var field = 'hand';
$scope[field] = 'value';
```

But when I tried the following it is not working. Undefined error occured.

```
var field = 'by hand';
 $scope[field] = 'value';
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Two version of code are equals.Are you sure that you copied the correct snippet?

Comment: yes, this is the correct snippet. check var field in both. first one is hand and the second one is by hand. it is not accepting the space between words

Comment: Can you demonstrate how you accessed the variables, you just show how you set them.

Comment: you shouldn't populate scope like this, try creating an object first `$scope.data = {};` and then filling it with `$scope.data[field] = 'value';`

Comment: angular.forEach($scope.sending_list, function(vv, kk) {
                 $scope[vv] = false;
            })

The $scope.sending_list is an array from database. example ['airways','courier','by hand']  the issue is it is not accepting the space between by and hand, others are working fine

Answer (score 0):

```
var field = 'to hand';
$scope[field] = 'value';

console.log($scope['to hand']);
```

Comment: the field values are generated dynamically. so i cant give the single quotes there

Comment: its field value generated dynamically or the key

Comment: it is the value from the array.  Take a look above. I have mentioned the array also

Comment: i have created the plunker with your example only : https://plnkr.co/edit/ruBkNk9GW5uqb2lmeaxP?p=preview, and it is working i did not get undefined error. Please check and give more details so that i can help you.

Comment: i ll try once again